# spark read schema types to create insert statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
root
|-- s_time: string (nullable = false)
|-- c_time: string (nullable = false)
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- sesh: string (nullable = true)
|-- event_data: struct (nullable = false)
|    |-- reason: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- status: long (nullable = false)
|-- ip: string (nullable = true)
|-- tags: array (nullable = false)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
|-- xxxx: string (nullable = false)
|-- yyyy: string (nullable = false)
|-- app: string (nullable = false)
```

I have the following schema above that is dynamically created. I then create an empty dataframe, from which I intend to mock up an insert statement dynamically.
A hardcoded example would be:

```
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('a','a','a','a',STRUCT('a',9), 'a',ARRAY('a'),'a','a','a')
```

So I convert my schema into dtypes so that I can 'in theory' dependant on the type it is.. build the above string.

```
schema.dtypes.foreach {  f =>
  val fName = f._1
  val fType = f._2

  fType match {
  case "StringType" =>
  println(fName)

  case "StructType" =>
  println(s"LOOOK HEREEEREEEEEEEE")

  case "ArrayType" =>
  println("ARRAYSSSS")

  case _ => None
}
```

Issue is I can never match when I search for a "StructType" or "ArrayType". When I print out the `fType` I would see something like :

```
StructType(StructField(reason,StringType,true), StructField(status,LongType,false))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way how to convert a schema to dtypes . But , you can loop with fields and use the dataType for each row .

This, works for me :

```
val schema = StructType(
StructField("s_time", StringType, true) ::
  StructField("c_time", StringType, false) ::
  StructField("id", StringType, false) ::
  StructField("sesh", StringType, false) ::
  StructField("event_data", StructType(
    Seq(
      StructField("reason", StringType, false),
      StructField("status", LongType, false)
    )
  ), false) ::
  StructField("ip", LongType, false) ::
  StructField("tags", ArrayType(StringType), false) ::
  StructField("xxxx", LongType, false) ::
  StructField("yyyy", LongType, false) ::
  StructField("app", LongType, false) :: Nil)

schema.fields.foreach { f =>
  val fName = f.name
  val fType = f.dataType.toString
  fType match {
    case "StringType" =>
      println(fName)
    case s if s.startsWith("Struct") =>
      println(s+"LOOOK HEREEEREEEEEEEE")
    case s if s.startsWith("ArrayType") =>
      println("ARRAYSSSS")
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Comment: if it matches on "Struct" there is then no way I can list the columns in that Struct etc which is what I need to do